# Expected value formula explanation in probability

Tags: probability

Could anyone explain me why we compute expected value as :

$E[X] := \sum\limits_{i} x_i p_i$

I understand the output of the formula but I can't understand why the formula works.

Comment: "*I can't understand why the formula works*"... How do you **define** expected value then, because that is the very definition that I am used to seeing as the definition (*for a discrete case*).

Comment: Closely related and possible duplicate: [need help with understanding expected values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050808/i-need-help-with-understanding-expected-values?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation of a definition**

I would change the question:

Why is this the definition of the expectation:

$$\sum_1^n x_ip_i?\tag 1$$

when the possible outcomes of a random experiment are $\{x_1,x_2,\dots x_n\}$ and the probabilities belonging to the outcomes are $p_1,p_2,...p_n$.

Assume that we don't know anything about probability theory and we have a source of random numbers $\{x_1,x_2,\dots x_n\}$ and we want to calculate the average of the random numbers poured by the source. So, let's denote the random outcomes of the source by $X_1, X_2, \dots X_N$. Here all the $X_i$ can take one of the values from $\{x_1,x_2,\dots x_n\}$ and $N$ has nothing to do with $n$. $N$ is just the number of the outcomes we observed. Preferably $N$ is way larger than $n$. Now, the average is

$$A=\frac1N\sum_1^N X_j.$$

Assume now, that the values $x_1, x_2,\dots x_n$ appeared $m_1,m_2,\dots, m_n$ times during the experiment. $\left(m_1+m_2+\cdots m_n=N\right)$

With this

$$A=\frac1N\sum_1^N X_j=\frac{m_1}Nx_1+\frac{m_2}Nx_2+\cdots\frac{m_n}Nx_n=$$
$$=\overline p_1x_1+\overline p_2x_2+\cdots +\overline p_nx_n=$$$$=\sum_1^nx_i\overline p_i $$

where $\overline p_i$'s are the relative frequencies of the values $x_i$ in our experiment.

Now, if we believe that the $\overline p_i$'s are good approximations of the probabilities then it will be intuitive to define the expectation as in $(1)$ because then we can look at the expectation as an estimate of the average if we calculate that based on a long series of independent outcomes of a long sequence of experiments. (Of course expectation and average have to be sort of synonyms in our eyes.

Then probability theory cleans up all this...